# ¿Que sintaxis de funciones debería usar?

Tags: javascript

he estado viendo a otras personas resolviendo un mismo problema, sin embargo, utilizan diferentes sintaxis a la hora de hacer una función.

¿Alguien me podría decir cuales son las diferencias? Un saludo!

```
 1. function (param) { };
 2. let x = function (param) { };
 3. let functionName = (param) => { };
```

Incluso vi algo parecido a esto:

```
let filtrado = array.filter(function (item){});
```

Comment: Quizás esto pueda ayudarte en la decisión https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030645/are-arrow-functions-faster-more-performant-lighter-than-ordinary-standalone-f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Forma tradicional de hacer una función.
2. El resultado que retorna la función será almacenado en la variable x para usar ese resultado posteriormente.
3. El resultado se almacena en la variable y se está usando una escritura de arrow function, que salió con la actualización de javascript 2015.
4. array.filer retorna un array con el filtro que se haya programado dentro de function (item) y se guarda el nuevo array en la variable filtrado.

Todas las formas son válidas, entre las arrow functions y los metodos 1 y 2 puede afectar el scope de las variables, dependiendo donde se usen.